# Variance of the difference of two Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ we know that the following holds regarding the variance

$$
\text{Var}(X \pm Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)
$$

We also know from the definition of Brownian motion $B$ that

$$
B(t+s)-B(t) \sim N(0, s)
$$

These two statements clearly contradict each other since the former adds the variances while the latter subtracts them.

Why is that? A Brownian motion is also a random varible, so why doesn't it satisfy the first relation above?

Comment: Your first statement assumes independence between $X$ and $Y$.  Your second statement assumes $s>0$ and independence between $B(t+s)-B(t)$ (which has variance $s$) and $B(t)$ (which has variance $t$): add them together and you find $B(t+s)$ has variance $t+s$, fully consistent with the first statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The general formula for non independent r.v. is
$$var(X-Y)=var(X)+var(Y)-2cov(X,Y).$$
Since $cov(B(t),B(t+s))=\min(t+s,t)=t$ we have that
$$var(B(t+s)-B(t))=t+s+t-2t =s.$$